# How to do the same but using .then instead of setTimeout? I have an error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I'm trying to add new bullet type to the database and show list of bullets with new added item.

Bullet class method "add" - adding new bullet type to the database

```
    static add(bullet) {
        sql.on('error', err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
        sql.connect(config).then(poolPromise => {
        return poolPromise.request()
            .input('description', sql.NVarChar(MAX), bullet.description)
            .input('amount', sql.Int, bullet.amount)
            .execute('dbo.usp_bullet_type_add')
            }).then((result) => {    
                var r = result.returnValue;  
                this.addPicture(r, bullet.picDescription, bullet.picture)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
```

How to do the same but using .then instead of setTimeout?

```
    router.post("/bulletAdd", (req, res, next) => {
        const newBullet = new Bullet(req.body.description, req.body.amount, req.body.picture, req.body.picDescription);
        Bullet.add(newBullet)
        setTimeout(() => {res.redirect("/allBullets");}, 65);
    });
```

I have an error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" index.js file

```
router.post("/bulletAdd", (req, res, next) => {
    const newBullet = new Bullet(req.body.description, req.body.amount, req.body.picture, req.body.picDescription);
    Bullet.add(newBullet)
    .then(() => {
    res.redirect("/allBullets")
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It dosen't work because your add method doesn't return anything
It shoud return sql.connect which return a Promise this would make your code work as intended.

```
static add(bullet) {
    sql.on('error', err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
    return sql.connect(config).then(poolPromise => {
    return poolPromise.request()
        .input('description', sql.NVarChar(MAX), bullet.description)
        .input('amount', sql.Int, bullet.amount)
        .execute('dbo.usp_bullet_type_add')
        }).then((result) => {    
            var r = result.returnValue;  
            this.addPicture(r, bullet.picDescription, bullet.picture)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```